# TCDPF Footer Font issues

Tags: php, html, pdf, tcpdf

I am able to change fonts in TCPDF such as using:

`$pdf->SetFont('aefurat', '', 12);`

The default line for footer is:

```
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
```

So I tried using  something like

```
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array('dejavusans', '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
```

but no good as the footer fonts simply does not change nor if I change the size too. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

My bad,
just need to override the default

```
public function Footer() {
}
```

Also there was setFont line that was also overriding the

```
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array('dejavusans', '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
```